# Anaconda python kernel can not be interrupted. Reinstalling can not work

Tags: python, windows, kernel, anaconda, spyder

I can not interrupt a running script in python3 kernel in Jupyter, Qt Console, spyder on my window 10 desktop. Ctrl+c and interrupt bottom from the menu do not work, just nothing happens. The same method works well on my laptop and Ubuntu desktop. I tried to reinstall uninstall Anaconda and delete the remaining files, then I tried reinstalling the new version of Anaconda. The problem still here. My window 10 on the desktop is just installed yesterday, so it is fresh.

I have one desktop and one laptop. Each one has window 10 and Ubuntu installed on it. My laptop windows 10 has no problem to interrupt. Interruption works fine in Ubuntu on both desktop and laptop.

Right now, my situation is:

Win 10 desktop: Interruption does not work.

Ubuntu desktop: Interruption works.

Win 10 laptop: Interruption works.

Ubuntu laptop: Interruption works.

My question is:

1. How can I fix this? Reinstallation not helping!
2. What is wrong (probably)?

Thanks you! I need to fix to do my physics assignment. My laptop are too bad and I am not familiar with Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.7?

Comment: Yes. I am using Python 3.7

Comment: This seems to be a [problem](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8013) with Python 3.7 only, so I recommend you to use Python 3.6 instead for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6 can key interrupt for me. But I have a solution for Python 3.7.

1. uninstall Anaconda
2. after that delete those files in `C:\Users\<your_user_name>`:
   .anaconda .conda .ipython .jupyter .matplotplot .spyder-py3
   This is very important step.
3. reinstall Anaconda.

It works for me.